If $A\subset B$ then $\int_A|f|-\left|\int_A f\right|\le\int_B|f|-\left|\int_B f\right|$
I am not looking for a proof.
Let $$P(S)=\int_S|f|dx-\left|\int_S f\,dx\right|$$
where $S$ is a measurable set and $f$ is a measurable function. Obviously, $P(S)\ge0$.
Question:
I just found that $A\subset B$ implies $P(A)\le P(B)$. Is there an interpretation/intuitive explanation for this monotonicity property?
The monotonicity is not apparent at the first glance. Is $P$ some kind of common quantities in statistics/probability?

Context:
This question actually arises in the study of the regularity of minimal surfaces, where an inportant quantity is defined as
$$\int_\Omega |D\varphi_E|-\left|\int_\Omega D\varphi_E\right|$$
where $D\varphi_E$ is a vector-valued Radon measure.
In a proof of the $C^1$ regularity of minimal surfaces, the author used the monotonicity of the expression above (Theorem 8.4 in Giusti's Minimal Surfaces and Functions of Bounded Variations). It was not obvious, but the proof is easy.
Proof:
Suppose $A\subset B$.
$$\begin{align}
P(A)
&=\int_A|f|dx-\left|\int_A f\,dx\right| \\
&=\int_B|f|dx-\int_{B-A}|f|dx-\left|\int_B f\,dx-\int_{B-A} f\,dx\right| \\
&\le\int_B|f|dx-\int_{B-A}|f|dx-\left(\left|\int_B f\,dx\right|-\left|\int_{B-A} f\,dx\right|\right) \\
&=P(B)-P(B-A) \\
&\le P(B)
\end{align}$$
where the reverse triangle inequality is used from the second to the third line.
